# What will reduce my rendertime?

Tags: rendering

What would reduce the render time? Should I get a better GPU or more RAM?

Comment: It really depends on what you're going for. both have their advantages and disadvantages.
My suggestion is: get both, but do not heavily invest in either one if you're not sure yet what you need.
Basic recomended requirements can be found here:
https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Comment: [This guide](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/) is great for speeding up cycles.

Comment: Actually There Is Many Things ..
I Don't Know All Of Them But,
<br>
I Know A Video Tutorial From Blender Guru That Can Be Usefull :
<br>
[Here Is The Video Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gSyEpt4-60)
<br>
**Here Is A Summary About The Whole Video:** [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJRu5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJRu5.png)
<br> **- I Hope You Find This Usefull -**

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your system specs, this answer will be a bit of a shot in the dark however, generally speaking, given a decent system with a modern architecture, your best bang for the buck will come with a "more better" graphics card. GPU rendering is an order of magnitude faster than CPU.

On my particular system, GPU rendering is 4 times faster than CPU rendering.

Think of it this way, a \$200 graphics card will likely get you better performance than \$200 in combined CPU and RAM upgrades.

There are also a dozen things you can do in Blender, not the least of which is play with the tile size (Render > Performance > Tile Size). This is just trial and error--so pick a frame, change tiles to 32x32, render, check the render time in the upper left corner. Change tiles to 256x256, repeat. Pick the faster one and try a couple values on either side -- if 32x32 was faster, compare 16x16 and 64x64. Values should be increments of base 2 (so; 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512...).

Answer (score 0):

To start, there are two ways of rendering: CPU and GPU. CPU rendering has been supported since the project began, and is the default method of rendering, using your CPU and RAM to render the scene.

GPU rendering can only be done using the cycles render engine, which was added later on. GPU rendering has the potential to be much faster, as long as you are using a good graphics card. This is because of the highly parallel architecture of GPUs.

Roughly speaking, you can usually get more performance per dollar if you purchase a good GPU over a good CPU. If you already have a good CPU, then more RAM will only increase the *size* of the scene that you can render, not the speed at which it is rendered. Similarly, on the GPU side, you need enough RAM on the GPU to render your scene.

In summary, if you already have a good CPU, getting more RAM will not help the speed. Getting a GPU at around or above the price point of your CPU should give you increased render performance. If you are looking to get a new GPU, you might want to get an NVIDIA based GPU, simply because they have been supported for longer and are thus more likely to be stable.

Comment: Note that even when rendering on GPU you are still using the system's RAM and CPU. Some processes are not done on GPU regardless.